# How windows form controls draw themselves?

Tags: c#, button, gdi+, gdi

When we use a windows form control like a **Button**,How it draws itself on the form?

Using **GDI**+,or **System.Drawings** for ***whatever else***?

Thanks for your time :D

Comment: Do you mean how to programmatically draw the button? (make it draw), or how does the system draw it (history of)?

Comment: I mean that how microsoft did it in .NET framework.

Comment: Why everyone downvotes my question?

Comment: Is my question off-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx

this is button specific but I think it helps get the idea accross.

Here is an excerpt from that link:

> The ButtonRenderer class provides a set of static methods that can be
>   used to render a button control. Rendering a control refers to drawing
>   the user interface of a control. To draw a button, use one of the
>   DrawButton methods. These methods provide a variety of options, such
>   as drawing text or an image on the button. If visual styles are
>   enabled in the operating system and visual styles are applied to the
>   current application, DrawButton will draw the button with the current
>   visual style. Otherwise, DrawButton will draw the button with the
>   classic Windows style. This is useful if you are drawing a custom
>   control that should automatically match the current visual style
>   setting of the operating system. This class wraps the functionality of
>   a System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer that is set to
>   one of the elements exposed by the
>   System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton
>   class. For more information, see Rendering Controls with Visual
>   Styles.

Here is some more specific information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a36fascx(v=vs.110).aspx

Execerpt:

> The common language runtime uses an advanced implementation of the
>   Windows Graphics Device Interface (GDI) called GDI+. With GDI+ you can
>   create graphics, draw text, and manipulate graphical images as
>   objects. GDI+ is designed to offer performance and ease of use. You
>   can use GDI+ to render graphical images on Windows Forms and controls.
>   Although you cannot use GDI+ directly on Web Forms, you can display
>   graphical images through the Image Web Server control. In this
>   section, you will find topics that introduce the fundamentals of GDI+
>   programming. Although not intended to be a comprehensive reference,
>   this section includes information about the Graphics, Pen, Brush, and
>   Color objects, and explains how to perform such tasks as drawing
>   shapes, drawing text, or displaying images. For more information, see
>   "GDI+ Reference" in the MSDN library at
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library.

Comment: I used term "button" as an example. I want to know how windows forms controls draw? do they call GDI libraries?

Comment: Did you even read the documentation referenced? What is a `Graphics` object?

Comment: Also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e430ef4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So how buttonrenderer does this? How it draws the graphics?

Comment: I added some extra info

Comment: Thank you @PseudoNym01,the information is  complete